# How can I align these divs with inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with text, but one should be aligned to the top left, and the other should be centered, but not on the same line as the first.

Like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
|Backstage
|Issue 4
|
|                 New Fish Species
|              Migrating To The Town
|
```

This is my current code:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; width:565px; text-align:center;">
    <div align="left" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;">
        <strong>
            <h3 style="margin:0px;">BACKSTAGE</h3>
            <h5 style="margin:0px;">Issue 4, June 16, 2003</h5>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; position:absolute;">
        <strong>
            <h1 style="margin:0px;">New Fish Species</h1>
            <h1 style="margin:0px;">Migrating To The Town</h1>
        </strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: divs]

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you explain this more? `one should be aligned to the top left, and the other should be centered, but not on the same line as the first.` Which one is which? And what do you mean by not on the same line as the first?

Comment: Added an edit @jmore009

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do set the divs to `inline-block`. You really dont have to do anything more than `text-align: center` on the second `div`

```
<div style="width:565px;">
  <div>
    <strong>
        <h3 style="margin:0px;">BACKSTAGE</h3>
        <h5 style="margin:0px;">Issue 4, June 16, 2003</h5>
    </strong>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:center;margin: 20px 0 0;">
    <strong>
        <h1 style="margin:0px;">New Fish Species</h1>
        <h1 style="margin:0px;">Migrating To The Town</h1>
    </strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9z78rp7/2/)

Comment: Nice, simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div align="left" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; text-align:left;">
        <strong>
            <h3 style="margin:0px;">BACKSTAGE</h3>
            <h5 style="margin:0px;">Issue 4, June 16, 2003</h5>
        </strong>
    </div>


    <div style="vertical-align: top; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; text-align: center;">
        <strong>
            <h1>New Fish Species</h1>
            <h1>Migrating To The Town</h1>
        </strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

This should get you on the right track; with a few adjustments. Look at some of the differences and that should help.